# Tensorflow: has no attribute 'numpy_input_fn'

Tags: tensorflow

I am using Eclipse's PyDev for tensorflow version:0.12.1
I directly copy the sample code from tensorflow documentation,
but a attribute is not found and it returned

```
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4,
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io' has no attribute 'numpy_input_fn'
```

Tried to re-download pydev and tensorflow but none of them work

The source code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]

estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)

x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x}, y, batch_size=4,num_epochs=1000)

estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn)
```

Comment: This seems to be relevant: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7579

Comment: Thanks! After upgraded to 1.0.1, it works!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and fixed it by upgrading:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

pip install --upgrade tensorflow

upgrade tensorflowd to '1.1.0'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to leave some feedback to the problem, instead of just posting code